# Xcode4 How do I play one timer and jump to another then back as a loop?

Tags: xcode, loops, nstimer

It's a bit more complex however...
I need two NSTimers:

1. myTimer1 will have a speed of 1 sec. intervals and play for 6
   intervals stop and jump to myTimer2...
2. myTimer2 will have a speed of 2 sec. intervals and play for 6
   intervals and then jump back to myTimer1
3. and continue this until a stop button is touched.

I have managed to only get the one timer to play and can figure out how to do the rest.
Here is the code synopsis I used:
.h

```
@interface sosTest8ViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UILabel *myCounterLabel;

IBOutlet UIView *greenView;
IBOutlet UIView *blueView;

NSTimer *myTimer1;
NSTimer *myTimer2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSTimer *myTimer1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSTimer *myTimer2;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myCounterLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *greenView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *blueView;

@end
```

.m

```
@synthesize myCounterLabel;
@synthesize greenView;
@synthesize blueView;
@synthesize myTimer1;
@synthesize myTimer2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.myCounterLabel.text = @"0";

myTimer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
    target:self 
    selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
    userInfo:nil  
    repeats:YES];
}
-(void)updateCounter:(NSTimer*)theTimer{
static int count = 1;
count++;
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d", count];
self.myCounterLabel.text = s;
[s release];

self.blueView.hidden = YES;
self.greenView.hidden = YES;

switch (count & 0x01) {//was & 0x03
case 0: self.blueView.hidden = NO; break;
case 1: self.greenView.hidden = NO; break;
}
//I added this if bit as my own way, but doesn't jump to the net timer properly 
if (count >= 3) {
[myTimer1 invalidate];
self.myCounterLabel.text = @"0";
myTimer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f
target:self 
selector:@selector(updateCounter2:)
```

### userInfo:nil repeats:YES];}

So this is the formula I've been playing with and before I added the "if" statement it worked and the two colored UIViews alternated fine. When I change the speed to two in myTimer1 to 2 that works in changing the speed interval. I just need help using a working syntax to add the second timer jump and then looping it.

It may not even be possible to do this, but I hope it is and someone can help me.

Many thanks.

--Rob

Answer (score 0):

I would create Two NSStrings:

```
NSString *countone
NSString *countwo
```

Then in your selector for your first timer:

```
if ([countone isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //do your stuff
    countone = @"1";
}
else if ([countone isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
     //do stuff
    countone = @"2";
}
else if ([countone isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
     //do stuff
    countone = @"3";
}
```

and so on until you get to:

```
    else if ([countone isEqualToString:@"6"]) {
     //stop your first timer
     //start your second timer
    countone = @"";
}
```

And you can do exactly the same for your second timer, just the orher way round so that at the end you start your first timer, and like that it loops over and over!
And to stop the timer do:

```
[Timer invalidate];
Timer=nil;
```

Comment: Thanks for this option... but I couldn't get it to work. I 'm new to Xcode, and thought that countone/countwo needed to get a value from somewhere.
I tried this modification but it didn't work either:

    float float2=[myCounterLabel.text floatValue];
        if (float2 == 0){
            //do your stuff
            self.blueView.hidden = YES;
    }
        else if (float2 == 1){
            //do your stuff
            self.blueView.hidden = NO;
        }
        else if (float2 == 2){... and so on

Comment: RE the garbled code example above...I'm new to this site, and can't get the code to format in the reply area, but if you read through it  you'll see I was grabbing the value of the counter output (myCounterLabel) and trying if / else if thing.

Comment: Ok what exactly isn't working? I have used the same method (but just with ine timer) in one of my app store apps and its working fine, please describe whats not working